# sorl thumbnail + django issues in production

Tags: django, permissions, sorl-thumbnail

I'm using sorl thumbnail with Django.  On my local setup it works fine, but in production the thumbnails are not made.

My code looks like this:

```
{% load thumbnail %}
{% thumbnail up.image "32x32" crop="center" as im %}
<img src="{{ im.url }}" width="{{ im.width }}" height="{{ im.height }}">
{% empty %}
<img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}/images/missing_small.png" alt="" title="" />
{% endthumbnail %}
```

I enabled logging and the trace looks like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

[...]

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/PIL/ImageFile.py", line
215, in load
raise_ioerror(e)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/PIL/ImageFile.py", line
52, in raise_ioerror
raise IOError(message + " when reading image file")

IOError: broken data stream when reading image file
```

The error isn't very helpful since the file is there and is readable by all.  I'm not sure how to get a more explicit error, or what to try and fix.

And then more baffling is the fact that it works using `manage.py shell`

```
In [1]: from sorl.thumbnail import get_thumbnail

In [2]: im = get_thumbnail('/myproject/static/images/user_profiles/1/11-20-2010-2_5.jpg',
'32x32', crop='center' )

In [3]: im
Out[3]: <sorl.thumbnail.images.ImageFile object at 0x29fe090>

In [4]: im.url
Out[4]: 'http://example.com/cache/ff/31/ff318b4a995ff345d1d48e79b67ec62b.jpg'
```

It made the thumbnail, just won't make one via the template code.

Anyone?

Comment: It still sounds like a permission problem to me. Django over HTTP will be running under the webserver's user and group, whereas I'm pretty sure the shell management command is running under your user and group. Make sure the entire path for that file as well as the file itself is readable by the webserver's user and/or group.

Comment: It does not appear to be a permissions issue.  My web server runs as user www-data.  I have recursively chown'd my entire application directory to that user and group.  Every path down to and including the cache directory is writable by world.  Same issue persists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tried everything.  Ended up solving itself with a newer Linux distro.  Wouldn't work on Ubuntu 10.04 but after that it works fine for me, 11.04, 11.10, etc.

Answer (score 4):

A solutions for lazy people like me is to try another THUMBNAIL_ENGINE in the settings file.

I was facing the same problem. As it obviously results from problems with the image library, for my case I've decided to simply use a different image library - and it worked. Currently there are 3 possible image libraries: PIL (default), Pgmagick, and ImageMagick/GraphicsMagick. Details are explained [here](https://github.com/sorl/sorl-thumbnail/blob/master/docs/reference/settings.rst).

Of course, one of the alternative libraries must be installed on the server. Otherwiese, this solution won't work.

Answer (score 2):

Have you done your syncdb?

Run this to check : python manage.py thumbnail cleanup

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: uninstall all versions of `ligjpeg` dev files except 6.2. Uninstall all versions of `PIL`. Install an recent `sorl.thumbnail` and  `PIL-1.1.7` into a virtualenv using `pip` so that `PIL` compiles against `libjpeg6.2`.

Detailed answer:

I had a lot of trouble with this on a site I mantain - turns it was due to version conflicts between `PIL`, `libjpeg` and `sorl` - someone had installed lots of versions of all of them. I had to strip it down to a single install of `PIL1.1.7`, `libjpeg6.2` and `sorl.thumbnail 11.9`

Here's what I had to do (this assumes you're using virtualenv. If you're not, well now's a good time to start):

```
yum erase python-imaging
```

oh wait, it was also installed via easy_install so I also have to remove PIL from site-packages:

```
easy_install -mxN PIL
rm -rf  /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/PIL /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/PIL.pth
```

Now I uninstall PIL from my virtualenv

```
pip uninstall PIL
```

there seems to be a bug in the version of pip i'm using - I have to remove stuff in the virtualenv build dir or pip won't install a later version

```
rm -rf /path/to/virtualenv/build/PIL/
```

now I have to remove the versions of libjpeg that I don't want... You should probably do

```
apt-get remove libjpeg8 libjpeg8-dev
```

... or whatever incantation is necessary. Of course if you have other stuff that depends on that version of `libjpeg` then you're in an interesting situation. I'm sure you can get `PIL` to install and build against a specific version of `libjpeg`. Then maybe you can get `libjpeg8` to work ok with this - please reply if you do.

On my trainwreck of a server both `libjpeg7` and `libjpeg8` dev files had been installed from source (in addition to the package manager installed version 6.2 - hilarious eh?) so I had to download the source for both `libjpeg7` and `libjpeg8`, run `./configure` and then `./make uninstall`. There were still some libs left in `/usr/local/lib/` so I had to do `rm /usr/local/lib/libjpeg*`.

I should have probably just done that last bit but wanted to be thorough.

Check that there are no other installs or remnants of installs of `PIL` or `libjpeg` on your system.

Now you can start afresh...

```
yum install libjpeg-devel
```

On this battered old CentOS box that gets version 6.2 which seems to work best with `PIL1.1.7`. On recent Debian/Ubuntu you'd have to run

```
apt-get install libjpeg62-dev
```

now in my virtualenv run

```
pip install PIL sorl-thumbnail
```

restart webserver. happiness.