# sorl-thumbnail unable to create cache

Tags: django, sorl-thumbnail

I'm using thumbnail to display image previews. However, thumbnail is not able to create cache folder and thumbnail_kvstore in mysql database is always empty.

Here is my code:
In settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
...
'sorl.thumbnail',
)
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/').replace('\\','/')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

In urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
...
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

In models.py:

```
from sorl.thumbnail import ImageField

class Image(models.Model):
    file = models.ImageField(upload_to="images")
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

In template：

```
{% thumbnail image "100x100" crop="center" as im %}
    <img src="{{ im.url }}" width="{{ im.width }}" height="{{ im.height }}">
{% endthumbnail %}
```

The im.url generated by thumbnail looks like "/media/cache/6f/9d/6f9dc8d01bf2a23448525d0902a63cd6.jpg"

However, there is no cache folder generated under media/ and my images are stored in media/images. Also the thumbnail_kvstore table in mysql database is always empty.

I have seen several similar questions([Question1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12605974/sorl-thumbnail-not-creating-thumbnails) or [Question2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12767425/django-sorl-thumbnail-does-not-display-images)). It seems that MEDIA_ROOT or MEDIA_URL is not properly configured. Could anyone help me here?

Comment: Have you tried a solution mentioned here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6312344/sorl-thumbnail-django-issues-in-production

Comment: I don't think that is my problem. I set THUMBNAIL_DEBUG=True but I am not getting any errors.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I was using the wrong the ImageField. In models.py, I shoule use *sorl.thumbnail.ImageField*, instead of the built-in *django.db.models.ImageField*.